# MySQL - Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'task_log_wip.task_log_task' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I have having a bit strange issue with a query. This query works:

```
SELECT task_log_wip.*
FROM task_log_wip
INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.task_id = task_log_wip.task_log_task;
```

But this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT task_log_wip.*, xmlform.*
FROM task_log_wip, xmlform
INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.task_id = task_log_wip.task_log_task;
```

Adding any kind of table to SELECT and FROM will produce following error:

**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'task_log_wip.task_log_task' in 'on clause'**

Table **task_log_wip** structure:

```
task_log_id
task_log_task
task_log_name
task_log_description
task_log_creator
task_log_hours
task_log_date
task_log_costcode
task_log_xmlform_id
task_log_xmldoc
task_log_uniqueid
task_log_javascript_executed
task_log_fm_related_date
task_log_draft
task_log_status
task_log_approver
task_log_approval_date
task_log_pre_delete_status
task_log_deletion_approver
task_log_deletion_date
task_log_orig_creator
task_log_wip_auto_save
task_log_orig_created
```

Table **tasks** structure:

```
task_id
task_name
task_parent
task_milestone
task_project
task_owner
task_start_date
task_duration
task_duration_type
task_hours_worked
task_end_date
task_status
task_priority
task_percent_complete
task_description
task_target_budget
task_related_url
task_creator
task_order
task_client_publish
task_dynamic
task_access
task_notify
task_departments
task_contacts
task_custom
task_xmlform_id
task_procedure
task_virtual
task_ypaccess
task_created_ts
```

Table **xmlform** structure (**task_log_wip** is connected with **xmlform** via task_log_wip_xmlform_**id**):

```
xmlform_id
xmlform_project_type
xmlform_project_type_parent
xmlform_type
xmlform_name
xmlform_description
xmlform_dtd
xmlform_edit_rule_value
xmlform_company_id
xmlform_department
xmlform_creator_id
xmlform_shared
xmlform_notify_via_email
xmlform_notify_via_sms
xmlform_notify_via_pager
xmlform_notify_via_instant_messenger
xmlform_report_severity_level
xmlform_hidden
xmlform_released
xmlform_restricted
created_by
created_timestamp
last_updated_by
last_updated_timestamp
```

Comment: You need to either join the table xmlform with some other or cross join it if you want the whole cartesian plan as your query suggests.

Comment: Either way there isn't enough information about that table to provide you with an answer...

Comment: What additional info I should provide?

Comment: The structure of the xmlform table and how did it relate with the other tables.

Comment: Added the xmlform structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to either JOIN or LEFT JOIN with the `xmlform` table like this:

```
SELECT task_log_wip.*, 
       xmlform.*
 FROM task_log_wip
       INNER JOIN tasks 
          ON tasks.task_id = task_log_wip.task_log_task
       INNER JOIN xmlform
          ON xmlform.id = task_log_wip.task_log_wip_xmlform_id;
```

The JOIN or LEFT JOIN choice will depends on your data and requirement.